# How to bind within for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have a following problem:
I run a for loop that web scrapes HTML tables. I have to scrape values from two different tables and bind them together. My R code is here:

```
html <- data$html

tables <- list()
races <- list()


index <- 1

for (i in html){
  try({
    url <- i
    table <- url %>%
      html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Form1"]/table[4]') %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)

    race <- url %>%
      html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]') %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)



    tables[index] <- table
    races[index] <- race



    raceDF <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(race), nrow=4, ncol = 2))
    date <- raceDF$X2[3]




    tableDF <- do.call(rbind,  tables)

    tableDF$Date <- date 


    index <- index + 1

  })
}
```

My code sucesfully does tableDF, however it does not add Date to each observation. It just put the same date for all rows, which is bad.

How can I fix it please?

Comment: Can you update your post with `dput(data$html)` ?

Comment: `date <- raceDF$X2[3]` means extracting the `X2` column of the `raceDF` table as a vector, then subset and take the 3rd value. I can't see what the `X2` column is - if it's the column of dates you want to add (rather than just extract the third value), then try removing the `[3]`.

Comment: `date <- raceDF$X2[3]` is the cell that includes the date - lets say 1.1.2010. i need this value to add into a new column in tableDF for all events that happened on 1.1.2010. So finally I will have 10 rows that corresponds to 1.1.2010, then 15 rows  that corresponds to 3.5.2010 etc. Do you understand my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe second for loop will help? But I don´t know how exactly..

Comment: Having your `rbind` inside your loops is causing tableDF to be overwritten on each loop.  You should move the `do.call` statement outside of the loop and perform it once on the entire list of tables.  If necessary add the date column to "tables[index]" within the loop so the tables list contains the data in the desired form.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e for reply. The problem is that "tables[index]" has a different length for each i. How can I add the date column that has different number of rows in each case?

Comment: Without having an example of what the data looks like, it is impossible to provide any meaningful advice.  I suggest deleting this question and asking a new question and provide example data of both table and race, then maybe someone can provide advice on how to bind those tables together.